# Google Tag Manager and Local Storage

Tags: local-storage, google-tag-manager

I am using localStorage sometimes within Google Tag Manager to remember classes or id's from a previous event within a macro. I use this in the case when there are multiple forms on a page with no ID. I save the ID or class of the submit button and use this in the firing rule of a tag together with the submitting of the form. The problem is that localStorage works when I am testing in Debug modus, but when published it does not behave in the same manner. Then suddenly it returns the current ID, so the ID of the form. The code for the macro looks like this:

```
var prevID = localStorage.getItem("previousID");
localStorage.setItem("previousID", {{element id}});
return prevID;
```

I have also tried to condition on the event:

```
if ({{event}} == "gtm.click") {
     localStorage.setItem("prevID", {{element id}});
}
return localStorage.getItem("prevID");
```

This way, the localStorage value should only change when a click event occurs, as the gtm.formSubmit occurs directly after the gtm.click event it should remember the previous ID no?

Any other methods to condition on characteristics of elements that triggered previous events are also welcome.

*There may be some small typo's in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you that much as I have the same issue. When using Preview Mode, the localstorage item gets set correctly but once published, it doesn't work anymore... Those javascript problems with GTM are driving me crazy.

But concerning your piece of code, one thing I noticed is that you should not set an item in a javascript code and then try to read it again just after that. GTM gets confused and returns the old data.

So in your case, you should do something like that:

```
var previousID = localStorage.getItem("prevID");
if ({{event}} == "gtm.click") {
     elementID = {{element id}};
     localStorage.setItem("prevID", elementID);
     return elementID;
}
return previousID;
```

EDIT: I just found out another difference between Preview Mode & Publish. Preview Mode evaluates ALL your variables, ALL the time. But when you quit Preview Mode and that your GA Tracking is working with the published version of your container, the variables are evaluated ONLY if they are linked to a triggered tag (or the trigger of a triggered tag).

For example, I wanted to set a localstorage item on every page load to keep track of a status, in order to do that, I had to do another custom JS that tests the custom JS which is setting the localstorage and always returns true. Then I used this new custom JS (containing the other one) to test a trigger that I added to my All Pages tag.